# Node.JS Express connect to Mysql (both Docker) ECONNREFUSED

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, docker-compose, econnrefused

I'm trying to connect express to mysql that running in docker

FYI.  both of them running in docker

It works when express runs in my local but not work when trying to run in docker

error code from docker :
`error connecting: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306`

app.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql')
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  user: 'admini',
  password: 'admini',
  database: 'cooper',
  port:'3306',
  connectionLimit: 10
})
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
services:

  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    ports: 
      - 3306:3306

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://root:example@mongo:27017/
```

Comment: You probably want `0.0.0.0`, not `127.0.0.1`

Comment: What do you mean by "running app.js in docker"?  The Node app is missing from the docker-compose file, so most likely they are running in different Docker virtual networks.

Comment: @MarcelloRomani yes it is i'm running  in different Docker Virtural networks.
// i have anthe docker-composefile

Comment: Then you should say that, and post that file as well, otherwise how can people help if you don't provide your full context? :-)

Comment: Anyway it's customary to have the app run as a service in the same docker-compose.yaml file as the db, so you can easily connect them by service name.

Comment: @MarcelloRomani ok i'll try iit  and sorry for how these formation was unclear   i just relize that gonna be diferrent between store all of service in 1 docker-compose.yaml file and seperate them

Answer (score 0):

Try switching host from `127.0.0.1` to `db` (the name you set in the docker-compose) when trying to connect from other docker containers.